# creating a site collection is taking too long

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, site-collection, performance

I have a SharePoint server with 10GB RAM & sql server with 10GB of RAM. now i want to create a new site collection inside our SharePoint server 2013, so i wrote the following command:-

```
New-SPSite -Url "http://vsps01/kb/CustomerService" -OwnerAlias "***\***" -Template "ENTERWIKI#0"
```

but currently it took around 30 minutes and the command did not finish yet , and there is not error. also when i check  the **"View All Site Collection"** link inside the CA, I found that the site collection was created, but if i try navigating to it i will get `http 404 page not found`, can anyone advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check.

- How many site collection you already have in the web app & Sizes?
- stop all the unwanted services on the SharePoint server. If you use the scripted installation then you have all services running.So please stop all unwanted.
- how many web applications you have, if you have more web apps, just delete the unwanted or stop their app for time being to testing.
- check the database autogrowth settings. should be min 256MB auto with unlimtied groth.
- also check the drive space on the both sql server and sharepoint server.
- If antivirus enabled, please stop it then try.
- Enable verbose logging and invoke the new-spsite command, then examine the logs.

Comment: i have only one web application and 2 site collection. my SharePoint server RAM is 10 Gb , and the sql server RAM size is also 10GB